# How to know that a computer is a webserver?

Tags: webserver

How to know that ? If I install `WAMP` in my computer , does it become a `webserver` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the definition of "web server", and not programming

Comment: It's a web server if you consider it to be a web server. There's no perfectly precise definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your services and you will see your server is up and running. This is how you realise your machine has become a web server now. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Name of the service is Apache.

Comment: Have you installed `Apache` separate? Then `Apache2` refers to that server. However that's in my case. In your case may be a typo which still says a web server is there, which is called `Apache2`.

Comment: Apache is automatically installed with WAMP !

Comment: Right click and see options. Then see `path to executable` it says where the exe is saved in.

Comment: Yes, Apache is automatically installed with WAMP. But still you can have a separate Apache server running. In my machine, I got two Apache servers (not running in the same time though). One comes with WAMP and other server I installed by my self. Hope this helps. Cheers!